# Visual Studio/Notepad++: Highlight repeat occurrences of selection text?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use Notepad++ for all my note-taking, copying and pasting, rapid prototyping, etc. It's freaking awesome. (Just wish it had some cloud storage instead! That's another topic though.)

Now, in Notepad++, when I have a script like that below, and double-click "foobar" to select and highlight it, everywhere else "foobar" appears, it's also highlighted:

```
function foobar() { var _foobar = "foobar"; return _foobar; }
```

Is there any way to get this in Visual Studio 2010? It's more a functional than stylistic feature, programmatically, I would imagine, so I doubt it's possible in VS. But it may be, perhaps?

Comment: You can get VS.Net to place a bookmark on each line where a search term exists - don't think you can get it to highlight the text, tho'.  :(

Answer (score 6):

There are extensions for VS2010 - [Highlight all occurrences of selected word](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) to highlight the same words. And [Productivity power tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=189202) to highlight all occurrences even if they are in the different words.[image: foobar highlighting]