# Visual Studio/Notepad++: Highlight repeat occurences of selected text (made of many words)?

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

I found this question [Visual Studio/Notepad++: Highlight repeat occurences of selection text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876753/visual-studio-notepad-highlight-repeat-occurences-of-selection-text) which answered how to highlight a single word but I'm interested in highlighting a selection of text made of many words.

And, at the moment, this is not natively supported
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it cannot be done with Notepad++

Comment: @Toto: and with a plugin?

Comment: @Revious: no plugin required, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Toto: ...it can be done with Notepad++, but takes a few steps. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the mouse, select the words (or phrase)
2. Then use menu: `Search`, sub-option: `Find...` (or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut)
3. Click the `Mark` tab
4. Click the `Mark All` button

Should see something like this:
[image]